# Netbeans IDE (6.8/PHP) - Custom Window Arrangement?

Tags: php, user-interface, netbeans, ide

I'm doing PHP development in NetBeans 6.8 and want to be able to switch between window layouts with a keypress.

I understand the IDE provides different "window groups" depending on whether I'm editing or debugging, but I'm looking for custom control of this.

For instance, I'd like to have a max-editor-view, where the editor takes up the majority of screen real estate... then press Ctrl-Alt-2 and have a second window arrangement display where the projects files heirarchy window appears on the left of the editor...  then press Ctrl-Alt-3 and have the variables/watches/search results appear below the editor... then press Ctrl-Alt-1 and display the max-editor-view again.

Something like that, anyway. Is it possible?

Comment: Great question. You may want to ask this on Netbeans community http://netbeans.org/community/index.html

Answer (score 2):

http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2008/04/top-10-netbeans-ide-keyboard-shortcuts.html

http://www.scribd.com/doc/7629741/netbeans-keyboard-short-cut

try this. I think you will find some thing here.